# why the created bmp image hasn't got high quality?

Tags: c#, image

I have searched a lot and used almost all preferred methods but i have not got the result of having a high quality bitmap image: the below is the code i have used:

```
ean13.Scale = 0.8f;
ean13.Scale = (float)Convert.ToDecimal(cboScale.Items[cboScale.SelectedIndex]);// it includes the sizes 
Bitmap bmp = ean13.CreateBitmap();
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
g.DrawString(tcc.Text, this.Font, Brushes.Black, 120, 80);// title
g.DrawString(bcc.Text, this.Font, Brushes.Black, 120, 1); //the price
g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
g.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit;
g.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.SingleBitPerPixelGridFit; 
g.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
g.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit; 
g.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.SingleBitPerPixelGridFit; 
g.Flush();
this.picbox.Image = bmp;
```

added the picture: [image]

added the expected picture[image]

Comment: Can you post an example of your expected result vs. your actual result? "High-Quality" is very subjective.

Comment: thanks for the downvote, you could have asked gently so i could follow your idea

Comment: Try not using cleartype.
You also assing it twice.

Comment: @user1440308 could you check my question again?

Comment: @r.hamd why do you assume that the *commenter* downvoted? Downvotes mean there is a problem with the *question*. And this question does have serious problems - vague problem description, the "expected" picture is simply empty. The code that actually saves or dispalys th eimage is missing. The *resolution* itself is missing - a low resolution image won't look so nice. The *Font* is missing - it may be that a bitmap font is used. Please post a *reproducible example*

Comment: dear @PanagiotisKanavos , i dont have problem with barcode, the texts of both price and title is my target. the code only displays the image in a picture box. for the FONT i havent thought of it and i will check it for sure.

Comment: @r.hamd and *that* is why the question was downvoted - you should explain this in the question itself. Do you think that with the code as is, someone else can reproduce the issue?

Comment: @r.hamd That should have been a prompt to edit your question rather than to reply to Panagiotis.

Comment: anything wrong with answering gentle people? @Aron

Comment: Comparing the desired number and the one with the bar code I see that the original desired one is probably rendered in color while the barcode picture is black and white. Black and white is necessarily pixelated. I am also not sure whether anti-aliasing is doing any good on b&w (perhaps just makes the font look fatter). By contrast, truetype on a color device looks really good, because it's designed for it. If you must have a b&w end result try fiddling with the rendering options, if not make the result colored.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider i understand your point of view, could you direct me somewhere so i could try it

Answer (score 0):

You should configure the graphics quality *before* drawing the text. Currently all these changes have no effect on the bitmap.

Comment: Oh, that could explain a lot :-)